# Unable to launch glade 3.18 which I compiled from source

Tags: gnome, software-installation, compiling, make, glade

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I have installed [Glade 3.18 for GTK3](https://glade.gnome.org/sources.html) by compiling it from source.

So once I had unpacked the tarball in my home directory it told me that I needed to install `gtk+-3.0`, so I installed it with (it apparently also installed 111 other packages):

```
sudo apt-get install gtk+-3.0
```

I then ran:

```
cd ~/glade-3.18.3
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

And although it claims to have installed itself correctly, when I launch it through the GUI nothing happens, and when I do so through Terminal I get this output and it exits:

```
glade: error while loading shared libraries: libgladeui-2.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So why am I getting this error? Have I done something wrong? And how do I fix it so that it launches and works properly?

Comment: See if the answer here works (changing the version number from 1 to 2):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25756745/1175053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why am I getting this error?

You need `libgladeui-2.so.6` (and probably other libraries) in order to run `glade`;

Quickly searching for `libgladeui-2.so.6` using `apt-file` shows that it's contained in the package `libgladeui-2-6`:

```
% apt-file search libgladeui-2.so.6
libgladeui-2-6: /usr/lib/libgladeui-2.so.6
libgladeui-2-6: /usr/lib/libgladeui-2.so.6.1.3
```

However even installing the package you'll keep getting that error for each missing library until all the dependencies are fully satisfied, since you didn't install any dependency;

The quickest solution would be to install the dependencies for the version in the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep glade
```

And in 99% of the cases that will make the manually compiled version run immediately afterwards;

However bear in mind that using `build-dep`:

- If the manually compiled version requires additional libraries, you'll have to install them manually (this *might* require compiling them in case they're not in the repositories);
- If the version in the repositories requires additional libraries, additional libraries will be installed;
- If the manually compiled version requires an updated version of some libraries, you'll have to update them manually (this *will* require compiling them).